# Minimum age of cats, to be safely administered Gabapentin?

Tags: cats, medicines, fear, anxiety, stress

[Gabapentin](https://www.drugs.com/medical-answers/gabapentin-safe-cats-3572423/) is prescribed by veterinarians for cats, for fear, anxiety, or stress (example: to be administered to a cat before a vet office visit, to reduce those symptoms in that situation).

**Is there any minimum age that a cat should be, to safely be administered Gabapentin?**